# Facebook Like to save to PHP database

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

We're integrating Facebook Like to our website and we wanted to get the number of likes to save this to our database and send the data being liked to our customers later one. I'm wondering if it's possible since the facebook like was iframed to the site.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to get the amount of Facebook likes for your page:

```
$json = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id); // $id = page id
$json = json_decode($json,true);

$likes = $json['likes'];
```

You can check what other values are available by going to the link yourself.

For example, the Stackoverflow Facebook page: http://graph.facebook.com/11239244970